# PHP nusoap how to remove array wrapper element from response

Tags: php, soap, nusoap

I am using PHP nusoap library to create a webservice. The service returns 2 fields and an array of users and soap body is formatted as below:

```
<company></company>
<noOfUsers></noOfUsers>
<users>
    <user>
      .......
    </user>
    <user>
      .......
    </user>
    <user>
      .......
    </user>
</users>
```

How can i change this response to remove the users wrapper so that the response looks like:

```
<company></company>
<noOfUsers></noOfUsers>
<user>
.......
</user>
<user>
.......
</user>
<user>
.......
</user>
```

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:** you can’t

This is impossible because valid XML document can not have top-level nodes with same names. I bet there should be kinda hack/workaround, but I woul suggest you not to enter this territory and deal with what’s being generated by default.